# Hash/encrypt an array of objects

Tags: javascript, encryption, hash

How do I create a hash, as in SHA-256, from an array of objects? I tried a couple of ways, but can't get them to work.

**I want to check if the data changed by comparing the before and after hashes.**

```js
let data = [
  {foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz"},
  {foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz"},
  {foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz"},
];

hash(data) // 487f7b22f68312d2c1bbc93b1aea445b

data[0].foo = "changed";

hash(data) // 7663d8c57a4fe7d83db6bbc1bff52586
```

Comment: looks like the hash returned by your undiscolsed `hash` function actually changed - what's the problem?

Comment: It's an example. I don't actually have it working. I think my problem was that I am passing an object, instead of a string. I guess I should stringify it.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work because I was passing an object, rather than a string.

```js
const SHA256 = require("crypto-js/sha256");

let data = [
  { foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz" },
  { foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz" },
  { foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz" },
  { foo: "foo", bar: "bar", baz: "baz" }
];

let foo = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(SHA256(foo).toString());
```

Comment: Please be aware that hashing requires the *exact* string to be available in order for the hash to match. You might have trouble with the encoding or [object ordering](https://medium.com/@ty0h/preserving-json-object-keys-order-in-javascript-python-and-go-language-170eaae0de03#5b82), since the implementation of `JSON.stringify` might change in your browser. Also, compatibility with other JSON implementations in other languages might not be available.

Answer (score -2):

You pretty much done it.

```
let dataHash1 = hash(data);
data[0].foo = "changed";
let dataHash2 = hash(data);

let isChanged = false;
if (dataHash2 === dataHash2) {
  isChanged = true;
}
```

The isChanged variable will be true if your data changed and false if your data remain the same.